# presentViewController width in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, landscape

When presenting a view controller, I would like it to take 100% of the screen width/height on iPhone portrate mode, but take part of the screen in landscape (like this):

[image: Landscape]

And to be partial on iPad. The following code does everything except the partial on iPhone landscape:

```
SQLProEditConnetionViewController * editConnectionViewController =
    [[SQLProEditConnetionViewController alloc] initWithConnectionModel: nil];

editConnectionViewController.delegate = self;

UINavigationController * navController =
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: editConnectionViewController];

navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
navController.modalTransitionStyle   = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
navController.preferredContentSize   = CGSizeMake(320, 620); // size of popup view

[self presentViewController: navController
                   animated: YES
                 completion: nil];
```

Any ideas how I can properly get this to work for iPhone landscape mode?

Comment: You would probably want to use a container view to achieve this instead of just presenting a `UIViewController` over the current one. Check at the documentation from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW13 (especially using `addChildViewController:` and setting its frame over the current `UIViewController`).

Answer (score 0):

**Change this:** `modalPresentationStyle` in your code.

```
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
```

Hope this will work...!!

Comment: No, that still covers everything completely as seen here: http://i.imgur.com/JLrM2Vt.png.

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone and iPod touch, the presented view is always full screen. On iPad, the presentation depends on the value in the modalPresentationStyle property.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was seeing this due to the iPhone SE simulator. On larger devices it works how I want it.